# Что означает запись !!arr.indexOf('green')

Tags: javascript

```
var arr=['red', 'blue', 'green'];

alert(!!arr.indexOf('green'));
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/10467475/2076787

Answer (score 4):

Конкретно с `indexOf()` это сомнительная идея. Поскольку `!!arr.indexOf(item)` будет проверять что указанный элемент не является первым элементом в массиве или вообще там отсутствует. Лично я не могу придумать зачем это может понадобиться

Answer (score 1):

!! - Способ сконвертировать int в bool

Comment: Ну и почему же int?

Comment: @Qwertiy `indexOf` возвращает `int`, число скажем так

Comment: вот только в чем смысл indexOf превращать в bool? Ну ладно, если получится false - это значит, элемент есть в массиве, и он первый... А если true - как это интерпретировать? Как "элемент есть на не-нулевой позиции" или как "элемента нет"?

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что это проверка на то, является ли 'green' нулевым...

В противном случает этот код не имеет смысла, т.к indexOf возвращает -1 в случае отсутствия значения, а !!-1 === true